# Getting values from key value pairs PHP

Tags: php, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a registration form which saves user data to a text file via the  serializable method.

```
a:1:{i:0;s:44:"{"name":"Mario","pw":"3214","email":"mo@mo"}";}
```

I can deserialize the data however I am having some trouble extracting the value "Mario" from the key - "name". Code can be seen below:

```
$array = file_get_contents('user.txt');

$artikel = unserialize($array);

foreach ($artikel as $item ){
     echo $item['name'];
}
```

The error I recieve is Illegal string offset 'name'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serialized array of JSON strings.

So try like this

```
//$array = file_get_contents('user.txt');

$artikel = unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:44:"{"name":"Mario","pw":"3214","email":"mo@mo"}";}');
//print_r($artikel);

foreach ($artikel as $item ){
     $json = json_decode($item);
     echo $json->name;
}
```

> PS: Storing a password in plain text is very bad security, storing that in a simple file is even worse security, so I hope system this will never actually be used. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
>   and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json_decode` after `foreach` with `true` as a second parameter then you will get array as you want..

```
<?php

$arr = 'a:1:{i:0;s:44:"{"name":"Mario","pw":"3214","email":"mo@mo"}";}';

$artikel = unserialize($arr);


foreach ($artikel as $item ){
     $response = json_decode($item, true);
     echo $response['name'];
}
```

?>